# Adding "Attributes" to UserControl

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls, visual-studio-2005, ascx

I am looking to add attributes to my UserControl when I create it on my ASP.Net page.  How would I do this and how would I then access them in the code-behind of my .ascx?

In web.config:
    `<add tagPrefix="uc" src="~/usercontrols/uc-EmailForm.ascx" tagName="EmailForm"/>`

On page:
    `<uc:EmailForm ID="EmailForm" runat="server" />`

On Page Goal:
    `<uc:EmailForm ID="EmailForm" runat="server" ShowTo="False" />`

Code-Behind Goal:
    `pnlToAddress.Visible = ShowTo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create public property in your user control's class (in ascx.cs):

```
public bool ShowTo { get; set; }
```

Comment: I thought this might have been the case, but couldn't find any place saying that it was.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your class is something like this

```
 [ToolboxData("<{0}:BilingualLabel runat=server></{0}:BilingualLabel>")]
public class BilingualLabel : System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label   {

[Bindable(true), 
    Category("Appearance"),
    DefaultValue("EnglishText"),
    Description("English version of the text")] 
    public string Text_en {
        get {
            return text         }
        set {
            text = value            }

    }
```